# symfony2 form error

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

```
The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, 
but is an instance of class Ecs\CrmBundle\Entity\Customer.
```

Is the error I get in my browser..

FORM CODE:

```
<?php

namespace Ecs\CrmBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class CustomerDefaultConfigType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('customerStatus')
            ->add('tags', null, array('multiple' => true, 'property' => 'tag_name'))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'ecs_crmbundle_customerdefaultconfigtype';
    }
}
```

and the controller Action:

```
<?php

namespace Ecs\CrmBundle\Controller;

use Ecs\CrmBundle\Entity\CustomerDefaultConfig;
use Ecs\CrmBundle\Form\CustomerDefaultConfigType;
    public function newAction()
        {
            $entity = new CustomerDefaultConfig();
            $form   = $this->createForm(new CustomerDefaultConfigType(), $entity);

            return $this->render('EcsCrmBundle:CustomerDefaultConfig:new.html.twig', array(
                'entity' => $entity,
                'form'   => $form->createView()
            ));
        }
```

This is using symfony2.1 with composer...  Any ideas on how to get this working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the last form refactoring, you have to specified the `data_class` in the `setDefaultOptions` method in your type.

See [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-2.1.md) (search for `data_class`).

Edit: Correct link

Comment: I figured out the real issue, but no clue what needs to be done to fix it...

I just put my repo on a brand new server....  and when i run `php composer.phar update' (as i've changed my composer.json a bit to include new vendors) it tells me: `Cannot parse version constraint @stable` so i run: `php composer.phar self-update` then the regular `update` and it upgrades everything to a version that isn't compatible with the entire project....  any ideas on fixing it so i don't have to upgrade the composer.phar or whatever?

Comment: The `composer.phar update` update all your dependencies. Even symfony himself. Maybe some of your vendors are not compatible with the latest version for now? But without more informations, i don't have any solution for you... :S Maybe you can try to check the symfony-standard composer.lock file? You should probably ask a new question with your composer.json & composer.lock file and give more details about the error you get.

Comment: I'll have to do that tomorrow when I'm at work and can have said information at my finger tips...  Thanks for the help thus far...