# Symfony2 - Establish one form parameter from outside so cannot be modified by the users

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I have a CRUD for one of my entities in Symfony2. In order to create a new entry, I have two controller functions:

```
public function newAction($id) {

    $entity = new Clientes();

    // Get the reference to the Login entity using its ID
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $ref_login = $em->getReference('LoginBundle:Login', $id);       

    // Put the retrieved reference to the entity
    $entity->setLogin($ref_login);

    $form = $this->createForm(new ClientesType(), $entity);

    return $this
            ->render('MovinivelBundle:Persona/Clientes:new.html.twig',
                    array('entity' => $entity,
                            'form' => $form->createView(),));
}

public function createAction(Request $request) {

    $entity = new Clientes();

    $form = $this->createForm(new ClientesType(), $entity);
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();               

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('clientes'));
    }

    return $this
            ->render('MovinivelBundle:Persona/Clientes:new.html.twig',
                    array('entity' => $entity,
                            'form' => $form->createView(),));
}
```

In the previous code I added the $id input parameter to the newAction() function because I want it to be established from outside, because each of this Clientes is additional info of Login and has to be linked.

In the ClientesType form I have the following:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('login')
        ->add('direccion')
        ->add('localidad')
        ->add('provincia')
        ->add('telefono')
    ;
}
```

So far it works. In my form, the login parameter is chosen depending on the $id value. But the thing is that I want the login parameter to be fixed once the form is created, so the user cannot modify it from the form, but only calling the newAction($id) function with the appropiate value.

The thing is that if I delete the ->add('login') line in the FormType, it doesn't work anymore. It comes to my mind two options:

- Hide somehow the 'login' in the form, but keeping it working, although I don't know how, or
- pass to the createAction the $id parameter along with the $request one as input parameters, but I cannot figure out how do it either.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I came out with the solution. All I was looking for is actually the following:

```
<div style="display:none">
{{ form_rest(form) }}
</div>
```

Typing this at the end of the template after having shown explicitly any other form field avoids any user to modify the fields I don't want to, while it still sends the info using the $POST method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a [`hidden`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html) field type:

```php
public function buildForm(...)
{
    $builder
        ->add('login', 'hidden')
        // ...
    ;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but before rendering the form I get the following error: The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class Proxies\__CG__\Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Login. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to "Proxies\__CG__\Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Login" or by adding a view transformer that transforms an instance of class Proxies\__CG__\Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Login to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.

Comment: @Vynith That's not because the wrong type, but because you need to set a `data_class` option in your `Type` class if you use an entity in Symfony2.1. More information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10903756/1149495

Comment: I added this: ->add('login', 'hidden', array('data_class' => 'Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Login')) but now I get another error, this time after sending the form: Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in /Users/luis/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php line 1358